# ¿Cómo pasar un arreglo por medio de get?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando pasar un arreglo por medio de `get`, para no hacer muchos cambios en lo que ya tengo montado, y pues, me hicieron un requerimiento, el caso es que no sé de qué manera hacerlo, ya que, el `url` lo genero desde `javascript`, he estado investigando, pero pues, aún no tengo resultados, dejo lo que he hecho

`JS`

```
function filtros(){
        var sede = document.getElementById("sede").value;
        var sigla = document.getElementById("sigla");
        var dia = document.getElementById("dia").value;
        var hasta = document.getElementById("diaHasta").value;
        var mes = document.getElementById("mes").value;
        var ano = document.getElementById("year").value;
        var action = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=todos";
        var cont=0;
        var siglas = $("#sigla").serializeArray();
        $("#sigla option:selected").each(function(){
            cont++;
        });

        if(dia != 0){
            action += "&fecha=" + ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
            if(hasta != 0){
                action += "&hasta=" + hasta;
            }
        }else if(mes != 0 && ano != 0){
            action += "&mes=" + mes + "&ano=" + ano
        }
        if(sede != 0){
            action += "&sede=" + sede;
        }
        if (cont != 0) {
            action += "&" + jQuery.param(siglas);
        }
        location.href = action;
    }
```

Sí hay una forma de hacerlo pues me ayudarían mucho, puede ser en `php` también, pero la url no sé como pasarla. Gracias

Comment: Si los navegadores que deben ser soportardos por tu aplicación son compatibles, te recomiendo que uses URLSearchParams para generar parámetros de URLs, ya que va a ser más fácil trabajar con ellos y vas a generar código menos propenso a errores: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: Voy a revisarlo, gracias

Comment: @ordago pero al momento de recibirlo en el servidor con php, se recibe igual normal?

Comment: Si, esa API para lo que sirve es para generar una cadena de tipo ?key1=val1&key2=val2, etc. pero en vez de ir concatendo tu los parámetros en a mano, vas haciendo myparams.append("key1", val1); myparams.append("key2", val2). Esa cadena es lo que luego en tu caso le pasas a location.href

Comment: Ah, ya entiendo, pero cómo mandaría un arreglo?

Comment: Si quieres mandar un array, cuidado al mandarlo con GET, ya que la URL tiene un tamaño máximo y lo puedes sobrepasar. Si es posible hazlo mediante POST. Si solamente puedes usar GET, puedes pasar los parámetros de esta manera &varios[0]=1&varios[1]=2&varios[2]=3. Luego en el server tendrás que formar un array con esos valores pero ya te llegaran como varios[0], varios[1], varios[2] lo cual no será muy dificil

Comment: Y esa es la única forma posible?

Comment: No, puedes pasarlo de varias maneras, puedes ponerlo todo en una clave separados por algun carácter válido: &varios=1|2|3... Según el backend que tengas puede que acepte los parametros sin indexar, es decir &varios[]=0&varios[]=1&varios[]=2. Pero al final del día, si lo vas a hacer por GET, tienes que serializar ese array en un string de una forma u otra.

Comment: Listo, pues metí los valores con separación de guión y les hago un explode